# If $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ on $(0,\infty)$, Prove that $\inf_{x>0}$ $f(x)=-1$.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, bounded-variation

If $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ on $(0,\infty)$, Prove that $inf_{x>0}$ $f(x)=-1$.

For all $x>0$, $f(x)>-1$ then $-1$ is a lower bound of $f$ on $(0,\infty)$.

I did it up to here. And I want to find a any $\delta$ to solve the problem, as in the following example. But I don't know what to do. I need some help.

Example: $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, Prove $\inf_{x>0}$ $g(x)=0$.

Since $0<g(x)$ for every $x>0$, $0$ is a lower bound of f on $(0,\infty)$.
Suppose $\delta$ is any positive real number. If we choose $x>\frac{1}{\delta}$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}<\delta$ and so $\delta$ is not a lower bound of f on $(0,\infty)$. Since $\delta>0$ was arbitrary, if follows that $0=\inf_{x>0}f(x)$.

Comment: $$-e^{-x}<-1+\varepsilon$$ $$e^{-x}>1-\varepsilon$$ $$-x>\ln(1-\varepsilon)$$ $$x<-\ln(1-\varepsilon)=\ln\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{-1}{e^x}$

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{e^x}$

Now, for any x in $(0,\infty)$,
$f'(x)>0$,hence f is monotonically increasing function
Hence,
$\lim x\rightarrow0+$, f(x)=-1 is infimum of f on (0,$\infty$).

I think ,this one is very easy to observe.

Now, to prove it in your way,
Assume, $ -1+\delta$ be inf of f on (0,$\infty$).
There for some y in (0,$\infty$), $f(y)=-1+\delta$

Now, $\frac{-1}{e^y} =-1+\delta$

$e^y= \frac{1}{(1-\delta)}$

$y=\ln\frac{1}{(1-\delta)}$

choose some x <y from here
On (0,$\infty$) & get answer